# How to correctly create static App-Shortcut on Android 7.1 ?

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, app-shortcut

### Background

Android 7.1 now has a new feature called "[**AppShortcut**](https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html)" . On the docs, they explain how to create static ones and dynamic ones, and they even have a [**sample app**](https://developer.android.com/samples/AppShortcuts/index.html).

### The problem

I tried out the sample, yet I've noticed that when I click on the static app-shortcut, it shows me a toast "app isn't installed".

[image]

Looking at the code, I've found a suspicious configuration (in "shortcuts.xml" file)  :

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="add_website"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/add_new_website_short"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/add_new_website"
        >
        <intent
            android:action="com.example.android.appshortcuts.ADD_WEBSITE"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.android.appshortcuts"
            android:targetClass="com.example.android.appshortcuts.Main"
            />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

It doesn't look good, because nothing in the app has this intent action of "ADD_WEBSITE" .

The dynamic shortcuts work fine btw (can be added via the normal launch of  MainActivity).

### What I tried

So I thought this should be changed. I tried to create a new activity and change this configuration to match the activity (action and targetCalss), but for some reason I still got the same toast .

### The question

What could be wrong in the code? What should be changed to fix it?

Comment: Is anything of relevance showing up in LogCat? Note that in this case the relevant messages might be tied to system processes, not the app's process.

Comment: The action string doesn't matter at all but it has to be present. https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/10/20/random-musings-7p1-developer-preview-1.html

Comment: The action being needed yet not being used for anything sounds like a bug. Have you reported about this (if so I will start it)? Do you know what is its purpose, that it looks this way? Have you found how to fix this issue? They also have "categories" tag. What is its purpose? I thought it's all similar to intent-filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strange, but you can fix this by changing
`android:targetPackage = "com.example.android.shortcutsample"`
(same as    applicationid) or
`applicationId "com.example.android.appshortcuts"` (same as package name).

Comment: Setting it to the applicationId of "com.example.android.shortcutsample" worked, but the targetPackage is already set to the package name of the app. It's exactly as I wrote, yet it didn't work. How come? And what's with the action and categories ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your "com.example.android.appshortcuts.Main" don't has this action

```
com.example.android.appshortcuts.ADD_WEBSITE
```

You can change this action to

```
android.intent.action.VIEW
```